# Chrome PNaCl app inline installation

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-nativeclient

I want to distribute a **PNaCl** app, **inline installation** and use the app **without leaving the current page**. I have published the app on CWS. The app needs some user permissions. Inline installation works and the app appears in the Chrome browser apps section. But, I get this error :

> "NaCl module load failed: could not load manifest url"

when I try to load the app using:

```html
  <embed id="testapp"
         width=0 height=0
         src="testapp.nmf"
         type="application/x-pnacl" />
```

This is the testapp.nmf file which is located in the .zip pkg that I uploaded to developers dashboard.

```js
{
  "program": {
    "portable": {
      "pnacl-translate": {
        "url": "testapp.pexe"
      },
      "pnacl-debug": {
        "url": "testapp_unstripped.bc"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Manifest.json in the package file looks like :

```js
{
  "name": "testapp",
  "version": "0.0.0.2",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "TCP/UDP test",
  "offline_enabled": true,
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon128.png"
  },
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "permissions": [
    {
        "socket": [
            "tcp-listen:*:*", 
            "tcp-connect", 
            "resolve-host", 
            "udp-bind:*:*", 
            "udp-send-to:*:*"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The HTML page is on Google's **blogspot.com** and verified successfully.

Comment: What is in `testapp.nmf` and where is it located?

Comment: (normally, you **edit** your question with new information like that) And again, where is that file? In your app? On blogspot site? Both?

Comment: Okay, so I don't understand what you're trying to do. **PNaCl** allows you to simply [put your module on the site itself](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/overview#link-nacl-in-web-apps), there is no need for an app in CWS. If you're putting that `<embed>` on your site, say, `http://example.com/awesome/`, it tries to load `http://example.com/awesome/testapp.nmf` (and fails).

Comment: Finally, what is your CWS app's manifest? What kind of permissions did you need?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Xan. What about the permissions? Is the user able to grant permissions in this case? I read in docs asking permissions is just allowed in packaged apps.

Comment: Packaged app is a self-contained thing; you can't really embed it in another webpage. To make something embeddable, you need to use the MIME type route (I think). Then it makes the most sense to use an _extension_. It all depends on the permissions you need - please edit the question to include the manifest.

Comment: @Xan Is it possible to handle a MIME type for a dummy file by NaCl packaged app (just for loading the app)? Does the app still need to show its own page? Please see [here](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/distributing#registering-native-client-modules-to-handle-mime-types)

Answer (score 2):

Observations:

- You can't use socket APIs outside a packaged app (since there is no way to get permissions for them otherwise).
- A [packaged app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps) is mostly self-contained: it's not something interacting with the normal browser, it's a preset collection of resources that is displayed in a separate window.
- A certain website can still communicate with the app.

Seems like you're trying to follow two guides at once, for a packaged app and a web app. PNaCl can work in the context of a web app by just placing the pexe and the manifest on the site itself; but you require raw network access, and it can *only* be requested in a packaged app.

You can absolutely use inline install to add the app to the user's machine, but you can't embed a module from it in a normal page.

Your module can only be embedded in the app's own pages. So if you wanted to show some UI, you need to make that a page packaged together with the app and show it with `chrome.app.window.create`.

If you absolutely need to expose functionality to a certain website, you can [list it in `externally_connectable` and use messaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/externally_connectable) to communicate with the app's background page.

An app always has an event page, that is a [page that unloads if it's idle](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_lifecycle). So if you just embed your module in that page by dynamically creating an `<embed>` element, it may fail. However, if you're using the `externally_connectable` method, you should be able to keep a port open, that would cause the page to keep running.